# PhpStorm upload to server and deployment not appearing in context menu on new project

Tags: phpstorm

I've just setup a new PhpStorm project and I've never had this issue before.

In the right click context menu, the **Upload to server.com** button is not appearing, and the **Deployment** sub menu button is greyed out. See image below.

[image]

I've added my server to the deployment section in preferences and I've tested the connection and it's fine. I have even highlighted the server as my primary server. I can browse remote host fine, I just can't seem to get the deployment to work.

[image]

I'm using the same settings from another project that is working, but I don't remember having to do anything else.

Can any one help?

Comment: Check other tabs, Mappings in particular. You may have a warning there.

Comment: I swear I put the forward slash in but yeah you're right, there was a warning in there. Thanks for pointing the obvious out :-)